# Cant get RewriteCond rule to work in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have the following path:

```
http://www.domain.com/cgi-bin/hsrun.exe/Distributed/Postphil/postphil.htx;start=DetectLanguage?Language=LANG_Icelandic
```

If the path contains the folder /postphil I want to redirect to a new domain

But I have not been able to get the RewriteCond rule to work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^postphil+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I have been using the on-line tester at [rewrite-rule-tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to try figure out something that works, but no luck.

Any idea on how to write the RewriteCond condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context can be important with rewrite rules.  If your RewriteCond is in a `.htaccess` file or inside a `<Directory >` block, there is no leading slash on the URI.  If it is in any other part of the Apache configuration, the URI will begin with a slash.

The reason for this is that in a directory context, the file path leading up to the directory in question is removed and that path always ends in a slash.

In your case, there is also all of this: `/cgi-bin/hsrun.exe/Distributed/` before the `Postphil` bit but you require the URI to start with `postphil` so the RewriteCond will not match for that reason either.

The end of the regex ( `l+` ) mean "one or more l" which is also a bit weird but since it **does** match a single 'l' that part should work.

If all you want is exactly what you said: "If the path contains the folder /postphil I want to redirect to a new domain" then this will do the trick, no need for a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteRule postphil https://www.newdomain.com/ [NC,R,L]
```

I used a 302 redirect rather than a 301 because browsers cache 301s.  Even if you change the target of the redirect, if your browser has already seen a 301 for that URL it will just go straight there.  You can change it to a 301 once you have finished testing and are happy that it works properly.

Comment: This solution is simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} postphil [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

### Please read this:

[Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

Comment: I already did try this and it did not work